# Stream 2 loops using java 8 and return outer loop object from inner loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, java-8, java-stream

I have a function like this:

```
public static Xyz getXyz(P p) {
    if (p == null) {
        return null;
    }

    List<Object> bs = p.getB();
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(Bs)) {
        return null;
    }
    for (Object b : bs) {
        if (b instanceof R) {
            R r = (R) b;
            List<Object> cObjects = r.getB();
            for (Object cObject : cObjects) {
                if (cObject instanceof C) {
                    C c = (C) cObject;
                    Object vObject = cObject.getV();
                    if (vObject instanceof V) {
                        return r.getXyz();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I wanted to change the code by using java 8 streams.
Is it possible because I am returning property from 1st loop inside the 2nd loop.

I tried these 2 ways. But its of no help and seems wrong:

```
public static Xyz getXyz(P p) {
    if (p == null) {
        return null;
    }

    List<Object> bs = p.getB();
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(Bs)) {
        return null;
    }

       Xyz xyz = null;
         bs.stream()
            .filter(b -> (b instanceof R))
            .map(b -> (R) b).forEach(r -> {
                    List<Object> cObjects = = r.getB();
                     Optional vOptional= cObjects.stream()
                        .filter(cObjects -> (cObjects instanceof C))
                        .map(cObjects -> ((C) cObjects).getV())
                        .filter(vObject -> (vObject instanceof V)).findFirst();
                     if(vOptional.isPresent()){
                         xyz =  r.getXyz();
                         return;
                     }
    });
        return xyz;
}
```

I tried this , but I don’t think I can collect the value that I need

```
bs.stream()
    .filter(b -> (b instanceof R))
    .flatMap(b -> ((R) b).getB().stream())
    .filter(cObject -> (cObject instanceof C))
    .map(cObject -> ((C) cObject).getV())
    .filter(vObject -> (vObject instanceof V))
    .collect(/*no idea if I can collect the value I desire*/);
```

Is using stream bad idea for my requirement? Or am I on the wrong path?

Comment: Rethink those checks required for `instanceof` and the explicit cast after it, they are the root of the complexity you're looking at.

Comment: So you basically have an instance of `P` that contains a list of objects that could be instances of `R` and if any such instance has a `C` which has a `V` you want to return that `R`'s `Xyz`? - That would mean you'd filter for `R`, then map to `R`, then filter `R.b` for `C.V` and finally collect `R.xyz`. - Sounds complicated? Well, it's your code ;) - and with all those cryptic names it's hard to reason, especially since it looks as if those `P` and `R` instances could contain lists of any type (those `List<Object> bs = p.getB();` etc.). Is that _really_ necessary?

Comment: There is no need for collect. Since you’re returning the first matching item, just use `findFirst()`, which you have shown to know already. Don’t use `forEach`.

Comment: @Naman the instance of is needed. Cant avoid.

Comment: @Thomas. Yes.. needed. Sorry for the naming conventions.

Comment: @Holger Ok. I will try that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```java
return bs.stream()
        .filter( b -> b instanceof R)
        .map(b -> (R) b)
        .flatMap(r -> r.getB().stream()
                .filter(cObject -> cObject instanceof C)
                .map(cObject -> ((C) cObject).getV())
                .filter(vObject -> vObject instanceof V)
                .map(v -> r.getXyz())
        ).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

**UPDATE**

[Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) mention in comment that it would be good to replace `flatMap` with `filter` so here is newer version:

```java
return bs.stream()
        .filter(b -> b instanceof R)
        .map(b -> (R) b)
        .filter(r -> r.getB()
                .stream()
                .anyMatch(c -> c instanceof C && ((C) c).getV() instanceof V)
        )
        .map(R::getXyz)
        .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Comment: Instead of the `flatMap` step, it would be more natural to use `.filter(r -> r.getB().stream() .anyMatch(c -> c instanceof C && ((C)c).getV() instanceof V)) .map(R::getXyz)`